# How to use nvprof on Android platform

Tags: nvidia

I meet a problem when using nvprof on MiPad(Tegra K1) Android platform.

It shows ======== Error: Application returned non-zero code 1, when i use nvprof test
But my code is just like this. It can't return 1. It works well when i don't use nvprof.
code like below.

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Detail steps:

1. download nvprof for android platform and move it to /data/local/tmp folder(the target hardware is xiaomi pad, Tegra K1)
2. write and compile the code and move it to /data/local/tmp/ .
   Compile command like this.

   ```
   GCC=$(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/gen_standalone/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++

   NVCC=$(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT)/bin/nvcc -ccbin $(GCC) -target-cpu-arch=ARM -m32 -arch=sm_30 -O3 -Xptxas '-dlcm=ca' -target-os-variant=Android

   $(NVCC) -o test test.cu
   ```
3. /data/local/tmp/nvprof /data/local/tmp/test